# How do I put input from InputBox into a cell?

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I have an InputBox where the user will type in the current month in the format of first three characters + Sale (e.g. JunSale).

I want to return this into a specific cell. This cell already has stuff in it (e.g. MaySale). Once a user types in the input, the cell will now read JunSale not MaySale.

My code gives me an error message:

> Compile Error: Method or data member not found

with highlight on the last line of the code.

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales Calc")
Dim ActSales As Range
Dim pastmthsale As String
Dim currentmthsale As String

With Worksheets("Sales Calc").Cells
    Set ActSales = .Find("Forecast Sales -->>", After:=Range("DH173"), LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not ActSales Is Nothing Then
        ActSales.Select
    End If
End With
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=-1).Select

pastmthsale = Selection.Value
currentmthsale= Application.InputBox("Enter the Latest Month with Actual Sales Data")
ws.pastmthsale = currentmthsale
```

---

This is the code I have now. The error message I get is

> Application-defined or object-defined error.

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales Calc")
Dim ActSales As Range

With Worksheets("Sales Calc").Cells
    Set ActSales = .Find("Forecast Sales -->>", After:=Range("DH173"), LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not ActSales Is Nothing Then
        ActSales.Select
    End If
End With

ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=-1).Select

Range(ActiveCell) = Application.InputBox("Enter the Latest Month with Actual Sales Data")
```

Comment: Remove the `ws`. before `pastmthsale`. Edit: you could just do `pastmthsale= Application.InputBox("Enter the Latest Month with Actual Sales Data")`

Comment: I don't get the error message anymore but it still doesn't do what I want it to do :(  But do you know why having ws. before pastmthsale throws an error message?

Comment: You are storing it to a variable. If you want to store it to a cell, use a cell like `range("a1")=Application.InputBox("Enter the Latest Month with Actual Sales Data")`

Comment: To answer `Dim pastmthsale As String` is a string variable which is not a worksheet object.

Comment: I've made edits and I'm getting an object defined error :') Do you spot where I've messed up?

Comment: Assuming your selection is valid, try `Range(ActiveCell.address)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this method - no Range() needed when referencing activecell.

```
ActiveCell = Application.InputBox("Enter the Latest Month with Actual Sales Data")
```

Comment: lol didn't even notice.